# Parallel requests with WCF Client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have serveral servers having the same interface. I want to use WCF to request the state for the different servers. I don't want to do the requests sequential because this may take too long. So I put each request to a separate thread, reduced the timeout to 2 seconds, wait for all threads to finish and return the states.

But it still executes sequential. There must be something deeper in WCF that hinders doing requests being executed parallel. Or what can I do? After searching the net for a day now I ask you. Please help.

This is the code:

```
public class StateCollector {

private ChannelFactory<IMyService> channelFactory;
private readonly string myEndpointAddressTemplate = "http://{0}:14502/myservice";

public StateCollector(){
    //Instantiating the ChannelFactory is expensive, so we just have one.
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyService>(binding);
}

public List<MyState> LoadStatus() {
    List<string> myAddresses = new List<string>(new []{"service1.xy", "service2.xy", "service3.xy" });

    List<Task<MyState>> tasks = new List<Task<MyState>>();
    List<MyState> results = new List<MyState>();

    //Start a thread for each address to get the state.
    foreach (string address in myAddresses) {
        Task<MyState> readState = ReadState(address);
        tasks.add(readState);
    }

    //Wait for all threads to finish and read results
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    foreach (Task task in tasks) {
        results.Add(task.Result);
    }
    return results;
}

private Task<MyState> ReadState(string serviceAddress) {
    Task<MyState> readState = new Task<MyState>(() => {
        MyService myService = CreateMyService(serviceAddress);
        StateResponse stateResponse = null;
        MyState result = MyState.NOCONNECTION;
        try {
            //This call is blocking parallel execution!
            stateResponse = myService.GetState();
            result = stateResponse.State;
        } catch (System.Exception ignore) {
        } finally {
            ((IClientChannel)myService).Close();
        }
        return result;
    });
    readState.Start();
    return readState;
}

private MyService CreateMyService(string serviceAddress) {
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(string.Format(myEndpointAddressTemplate, serviceAddress));
    MyService myService = channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpointAddress);

    IClientChannel contextChannel = (IClientChannel) myService;
    contextChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
    return myService;
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need cold tasks or `Task.WaitAll`. The WCF proxy generates Task-based async methods already. You could just write `var response=await myService.GetState();`

Comment: BTW tasks aren't threads. You don't need to create a cold task and start it with `start` as if it were a thread. This code is way too complicated. *Asynchronous* operations shouldn't use threads either. An asynchronous operation can run without using/blocking a thread. When it completes, it runs a callback to process the results. With `async/await` this is handled by the runtime itself.

Comment: As for the apparent sequential execution, it's standard behaviour to allow only 2 concurrent requests per IP endpoint. This can change easily by modifying the value of [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks,  @PanagiotisKanavos. Wrinting await in front of the call I get "StateResponse" does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Re tasks/thread, yes you're right. I think I need to learn more about the async/await stuff.

Comment: I set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10` but still no success.